# How to assign unique rank number for duplicate values in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rank

I have a large data set like the below example, How to assign a unique rank number to duplicate or repeated values with a combination of more than one column condition. like rank to be assigned with reference to cluster & value column.

[image]

Example data table & required output:

[image: required out put]

Comment: please paste your code so it can be reproducible. An image doesn't help with that.

Comment: Rankdata$Ranknumber <- with(Rankdata, ave(desc(Value),Cluster, FUN = rank))

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do:

```
library(dplyr)
x=data.frame(id=c(1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7), value=c(10,10,10,20,20,20,20,20,30))
x %>% 
  arrange(id, value) %>%
  group_by(value) %>%
  mutate(rank=row_number(value))
```